Reflective iridescent/chrome metal material that changes color based on the lighting
I'm wondering if can you help me out on how would I create this rough yet reflective iridescent/chrome metal material that changes color based on the lighting?



https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1605/iridescence-in-cycles/2358#2358 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82705/physical-iridescence-in-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50961/how-to-create-iridescent-glossy-tile-material https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/299159/cycles-pearl-like-material/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201128/security-hologram-sticker/201156#201156 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109899/how-to-create-this-colorful-metal-material

Hello and welcome. This question seems to have been asked before in multiple forms over time, and already has various answers but you never acknowledged any of them. We are not sure if you aware of the existing posts but none of the described techniques address your particular requisites, or you simply didn't do any research at all. Could you [edit] you post and clarify how your question differs from the suggested duplicates? Otherwise could you rephrase it to focus on a particular step you are stuck with?

Hey Durate, I've actually been researching this for several months but haven't quite achieved the exact result I'm looking for. I initially thought Blender might be limited for what I needed, so I was exploring different solutions. What prompted me to post today is that I’ve realized Blender can actually do what I’m aiming for, and I feel like now’s the time to achieve that specific material I’ve been after. I’ll also edit the post to clarify how it’s different from my previous ones and why it deserves a response.

Please edit it and clarify, then feel free to ping me, or vote to reopen.
